# Workaround to same-origin-policy, redirect to separate page?

Tags: jquery, same-origin-policy

I have a html page which needs to access a resource on a different server using an ajax request :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "externalUrl/myjson.js",       

        });
```

But because of 'same origin policy' I am unable to access the resource. As a work around I have modified the html page which just redirects to a new page on the separate server. This new page invokes the ajax request without issue as its being issued from the same origin. Is this an acceptable workaround ?

Comment: Have you tried fetching the external resource using `jsonp` as the datatype first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Same Origin Policy isn't a law or anything, just a measure built into browsers to prevent XSRF and stuff. If you've found a work around that works for you, there's nothing 'unacceptable' about it.

Comment: This highly unlikely to work across all major browsers/versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jsonp for the dataType attribute in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The remote server will also need to support jsonp. It will get around the browser security preventing XSS.

This will get around the browser security for XSS. The url you are calling to will need to return jsonp as well for this to work.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "externalUrl/myjson.js",       
        dataType: jsonp
        });
```